# What is the best way to dynamically check the types of a class that uses variadic inheritance?

Tags: c++, templates, variadic-templates

I am writing an entity component system for a 2D game engine that uses variadic templates to construct game objects. Here is the object class which is just the container for all components. I removed the unrelated stuff.

```
template<class ... Components>
class Object : public Components...{
public:
    Object(Game* game) : Components(game)...{

    }
};
```

The components are inherited by the object but I am trying to find the best way to check the type of these components so that they can correctly communicate with each other. For example, the Physics component would contain the updated position of the object. The Drawable component needs to get that position so it can be drawn in the correct spot in the world. I would like to add an update function to Object that updates each component and transfers whatever information can/needs to be transferred between present components.

Comment: Can you clarify your requirement, for instance with a bit more code? I am  probably missing something because if you simply need the Drawable component to use the coordinated from physics, simply write something like `void Object::update() {this->draw(*this);}`, assuming that you have `void Drawable::draw(const Physics &)`. This will work as soon as the right`Drawable` and `Physics` are in the variadic `Components...`

Answer (score 0):

polymorphism is what you want . 
Simply make all components like that :

```
public Object
{
 enum TYPE{
 COMPONENT,,
 GAMEOBJECT,
 ETC,,,
};
Object(TYPE id){m_id = id;}
protected:
  TYPE m_id;
  virtual void Update(void) = 0;

  virtual void Render(void) = 0;

 public:
  void GetTypeOf(void)const{return m_id;}
};

 class Component : Object
 {
  enum COMPONENT_TYPE
 {
  COLLIDER,
  RENDERER,
  ETC,,,,
 };
   Component() : Object (COMPONENT){/**/}
   virtual void Update(void){return;}
   virtual void Render(void){return;}
   };

     class BoxCollider : Component
     {
      BoxCollider(void) : Component(BOXCOLLIDER){/**/}
      void Update(void)
      {
        //to do
         }
       void Render(void)
      {
          //to do
         }
     };
```

then you can simply have a data structure of Object* or Component* 
and you can iterate through that way  :

```
   std::vector<Component*>::iterator components = ComponentVector.begin();
   for(;components != ComponentVector.end() ; ++components)
   {
      *(component)->Update();
       *(component)->Render();
        std::cout << "id" << *component->getTypeOf() << std::endl; 
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

The `Object` class inherits from all its `Components`, that means that actually it *is* all its components.
You can use this information to design your `update` method.
As an example:

```
#include <cassert>

struct Game { };

struct Physics {
    int position{0};

    Physics(Game *) { }
    void update(void *) { }
};

struct Drawable {
    Drawable(Game *) { }

    void update(Physics *physics) {
        physics->position = 42;
    }
};

template<class ... Components>
class Object: public Components... {
public:
    Object(Game* game) : Components(game)... { }

    void update() {
        int a[] = { (Components::update(this), 0)... };
    }
};

int main() {
    Game game;
    Object<Physics, Drawable> object{&game};
    assert(object.position == 0);
    object.update();
    assert(object.position == 42);
}
```

Here you can see as `Drawable` receives `Physics` when its `update` method is called.
The drawbacks of this solution are:

- The `update` methods of the components must get a pointer argument even if they do not need to refer to any other component.
- If there exists a component that needs to refer to more than one component, you have either to get two or more pointers as arguments of the `update` method or to cast a `void *` around.